# Can't access Angular from outside of the container

Tags: docker, angular5

I am running Angular on a docker container and trying to access it from my local web browser.

`FROM node:9.11.1 as node
MAINTAINER Tectonic
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "start"]`

I build using: `docker build -t act .`

And I run using: `docker run -p 4200:4200 act`

This used to work for me but doesn't now.  The error I'm getting from chrome is **This site can’t be reached 172.17.0.2 took too long to respond.**. I've tried going to localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200, http://0.0.0.0:4200

I've tried running other web servers and I can access them just fine : `docker run -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx`

Comment: what if you add `--network host` to the run command?

Comment: Didn't work either

Comment: and are you sure `npm start` starts a server on port 4200 by default?

Comment: Yes.  If I just run it locally, not in the container, then I can access it with no problems.

Comment: I believe dargueta answered this question if you want to mark it as correct so other users can find it.

Answer (score 3):

Is case someone is having this issue, you can run:

ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

And you will be able to acccess your application from host.

Comment: Thanks.  This solved my problem.  When I went into the container docker exec it ...  and did a curl -v localhost:4200 it worked.  I checked that I was listening on the outside port so I new it had to be some type of restriction.  I needed to allow ng serve to allow connection from other ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to allow all interfaces with the --host flag?

```
npm start --host 0.0.0.0
```

This allows angular to be accessed by all interfaces and not only as with serving the loopback interface which is necessary once it's inside a docker container.

Comment: Didn't help.  Although now I'm getting "localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Comment: This is missing a ```--```
Working one should be ```npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0```